# Как сделать обработку нажатий русских клавиш на клавиатуре

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно, чтобы приложение реагировало на нажатия **русских** клавиш на клавиатуре без использования EditText (клавиатура в приложении открыта).

Пробовал методы `onKeyDown()` и `onKeyUp()`, но они реагируют только на нажатия английских клавиш

Comment: У клавиш на клавиатуре есть свои коды. У русских и английских они разные. Их коды можно узнать экспериметальным путём

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как следует из документации:

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method.

Если перевести на понятный язык - это означает, что не гарантируется генерация `KeyEvent` на все события софт-клавиатуры.

Что делать тогда?

Ну например можно поставить [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) на ваш `EditText` (его можно попробовать сделать скрытым и в фокусе)

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете получать информацию о вводе из воздуха, система отдает их тому элементу, что сейчас в фокусе. Создайте на экране EditText, который будет невидим или находится за пределами видимости, программно повесьте на него фокус и перехватывайте нажатия в нем